# Windows API to extract zip files?

Tags: winapi, zip

In Windows Explorer you can extract a compressed folder (a zip file)

Is there an API or command line to extract a zip file using the same method programatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Check [Compress Zip files with
   Windows Shell API and C#](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/compresswithwinshellapics.aspx)
2. You could use [SharpZipLib](http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SharpZipLib/) which
   is free for a dot net project.

Comment: Thanks abmv. But the first link requires an external zip.exe file. Do you know where that zip.exe is from?
Apparently SharpZipLib cannot unzip zip files created using WinZip, can it?

Comment: I see it is from the other project. I wonder why can't you combine it into one

Answer (score 5):

You can use this VBScript script:

```
'Adapted from http://www.robvanderwoude.com/vbstech_files_zip.html

strFile = "c:\filename.zip"
strDest = "c:\files"

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

If Not objFSO.FolderExists(strDest) Then
    objFSO.CreateFolder(strDest)
End If

UnZipFile strFile, strDest

Sub UnZipFile(strArchive, strDest)
    Set objApp = CreateObject( "Shell.Application" )

    Set objArchive = objApp.NameSpace(strArchive).Items()
    Set objDest = objApp.NameSpace(strDest)

    objDest.CopyHere objArchive
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried the above function `Sub UnZipFile(...)` under Excel 2010 and it was **not** working: Run-time error '91' (Object variable or With block not set) in the line

```
Set objArchive = objApp.Namespace(strArchive).Items()
```

and the line

```
Set objDest = objApp.Namespace(strDest)
```

is silently also not working: After execution the `objDest` is still nothing!

Microsoft's `.Namespace()` accepts as parameter either an object, a string constant or a string variable. With string variables there are often suspicious problems, which are requiring an workaround:

```
Set objArchive = objApp.Namespace(**CStr(** strArchive **)**).Items()  
Set objDest = objApp.Namespace(**CStr(** strDest **)**)
```

or an alternative workaround

```
Set objArchive = objApp.Namespace(**"" &** strArchive).Items()  
Set objDest = objApp.Namespace(**"" &** strDest)
```

And the line `objDest.CopyHere objArchive` was also not working:  The destination folder remained empty!

Here a version, which is working in Excel 2010 and most probably also in other environments:

```
Sub UnZipFile(strZipArchive As String, strDestFolder As String)
  Dim objApp As Object
  Dim vItem As Variant
  Dim objDest As Object

  Set objApp = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
  Set objDest = objApp.Namespace(CStr(strDestFolder))
  For Each vItem In objApp.Namespace(CStr(strZipArchive)).Items
    objDest.CopyHere vItem
  Next vItem
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

For C# or VB users, you can check the answer from MSDN:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404280(v=vs.100).aspx

For .net 4.x, here is the sample code from MSDN

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.Compression;

namespace ConsoleApplication
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string startPath = @"c:\example\start";
            string zipPath = @"c:\example\result.zip";
            string extractPath = @"c:\example\extract";

            ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(startPath, zipPath);

            ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(zipPath, extractPath);
        }
    }
}
```